# g++: No such file or directory?

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, g++, sdl

*(On Linux, trying to set up SDL)* I'm having a time with makefiles, I'm finding them hard to learn. Here is the error I'm getting.

```
g++: error: game.exe: No such file or directory
make: *** [game.exe] Error 1
```

Here is my makefile. **(Any suggestions on making it better would be great. I've just kind of slapped together whatever I could find to work.)**

```
#Game Make file
TARGET = game.exe
OBJS = App.o\
   App_OnInit.o\
   App_OnEvent.o\
   App_OnLoop.o\
   App_OnRender.o \
   App_OnCleanup.o\

SDL_CFLAGS := $(shell sdl-config --cflags)
SDL_LDFLAGS := $(shell sdl-config --libs)
CFLAGS = -Wall -o
LIBS =
LDFLAGS = 

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
       g++ $(CFLAGS) $(SDL_CFLAGS) $@  $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(SDL_LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)
%.o: src/%.cpp
       g++  -c $(SDL_CFLAGS) $< $(SDL_LDFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET) $(OBJS)
```

Comment: Can you show the complete compilation output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either exchange `$(CFLAGS)` and `$(SDL_CFLAGS)` in the rule to make `$(TARGET)` or better remove `-o` from `CFLAGS` and put it directly before `$@`:

```
...
CFLAGS = -Wall
...
$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
       g++ $(CFLAGS) $(SDL_CFLAGS) -o $@  $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(SDL_LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

`-o` option should immediately precede the name of the executable file to be produced. In your original `Makefile` it is part of `$(CFLAGS)` and is followed by the C flags of the SDL library. Therefore the compiler tries to link in `game.exe` (the `$@`) instead of producing an executable file by that name.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I've been stuck on this for over an hour.