# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCImg

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I am newbie in C++ and Eclipse simultaneously...
I want to use CImg library but when I just used a line for it I have the problem that it is described below :

My code is:

```
#include "CImg.h"   
using namespace cimg_library;   
int main() {    
CImg <unsigned char> img(640,400,1,3); 
return 0;}
```

and the error that I get is :
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCImg
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I have searched a lot yesterday and I have tried many things that I found.
I tried almost everything for X11 library and pathread. 
I changed many times the flags in the settings of the project...
Thank you in advance.

PS: I know that there is a similar(almost the same question) here [g++: No such file or directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895879/g-no-such-file-or-directory) but in my case I can not change the makefile.

Answer (score 2):

CImg is a template-based library that is compiled 'on the fly' with your program, so it is not pre-compiled and thus doesn't have a libCImg.so or libCImg.a files associated to it.
You just don't need an option '-lCImg' when you call g++. Eventually, if you are using the display capabilities of CImg (which is the default behavior), you need to add

```
-lX11 -lpthread
```

on your compilation line, but that is all (and if you don't use CImgDisplay at all, those dependencies can be even removed by putting

```
-Dcimg_display=0
```

when compiling with g++).